# Undefined property: stdClass::$notifications

Tags: php, panel, onesignal

OneSignal PHP Panel Errors/Bugs

ERRORS:

INDEX.PHP

> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Invalid app_id format" } }
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$notifications in public_html/ONESIGNAL/index.php on line 68

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in public_html/ONESIGNAL/index.php on line 68

SENT.PHP

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$notification in public_html/ONESIGNAL/sent.php on line 38

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/ONESIGNAL/sent.php on line 38

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total_count in public_html/ONESIGNAL/sent.php on line 60

INDEX.PHP

```
<!--header-->
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<!--header-->



<!--sidebar-->
<?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>
<!--sidebar-->

<!--content-->
<div class="content">


    <div class="box-container container-25">
         <div class="box" id="div-1">
            <h3>
                Send Notification 
            </h3>
            <div class="box-content">
                <form class="form" id="send">
                <input type="hidden" name="send" value="true">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input name="title" type="text" id="input" placeholder="(Title) - max 50 character" maxlength="50" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="(Content) - max 125 characters" maxlength="125" required></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input name="url" type="text" id="input" placeholder="URL" required>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <button type="submit" id="sendnotifi">Send Notification</button> <i id="result"></i>
                        </li>
                    
                        
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-container container-75">
        <div class="box" id="div-2">
            <h3>
                Last 10 Sent Notifications
            </h3>
            <div class="box-content">
                <div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Delivered</th>
                    <th class="hide">Title</th>
                    <th class="hide">Content</th>
                    <th>Sent Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            
                <?php   
                    $response = Notifications(10);
                    
                    $return = json_decode($response); 
                    var_dump($return);
                    foreach ($return->notifications as $notifi) { 
                        if($notifi->data == null) {
                    
                    
                ?>          
                <tr>
                    <td> <?=$notifi->successful;?> </td>
                    <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->headings->en;?> </td>
                    <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->contents->en;?> </td>
                    <td><span class="date"><?=gmdate("d-m-Y / H:i:s", $notifi->send_after);?></span></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php 
                    }
                    }
                    ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

SENT.PHP

```
<!--header-->
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<!--header-->



<!--sidebar-->
<?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>
<!--sidebar-->

<!--content-->
<div class="content">

    <div class="clear" style="height: 10px;"></div>

    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Delivered</th>
                    <th class="hide">Fail</th>
                    <th class="hide">Title</th>
                    <th class="hide">Content</th>
                    <th class="hide">Notification ID</th>
                    <th>Sent Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            
                <?php 
                    
                    $limit = 20;  
                    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
                    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
                    $response = Notifications($limit,$start_from);
                    $return = json_decode($response); 
                                        
                    foreach ($return->notification as $notifi) {
                    
                        if($notifi->data == null) {

                ?>          
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?=$notifi->successful;?> </td>
                            <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->failed;?> </td>
                            <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->headings->en;?> </td>
                            <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->contents->en;?> </td>
                            <td class="hide"> <?=$notifi->id;?> </td>
                            <td><span class="date"><?=gmdate("d-m-Y / H:i:s", $notifi->send_after);?></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php 
                            }
                    }
                    ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

                <?php 
                    $total_pages = ceil($return->total_count / $limit);  
                    $pagLink = "<div class='pagination'> <ul>";  
                    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
                                if($page==$i) {
                                    $pagLink .= "<li class='active'><a href='#'>".$i."</a></li>";  
                                } else {
                                    $pagLink .= "<li><a href='sent.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
                                }
                    };  
                    echo $pagLink . "</div>";  
                ?>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to dive into some programming ugliness here to debug it. After the `$return = json_decode($response); ` line put `var_dump($return)`, then manually inspect what is in there. It might be overly obvious, but if it isn't, you can try posting that value in an edit above and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in ONESIGNAL/index.php on line 68.
I'm sorry I don't know much about PHP.

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of the code that I gave you, like this: `var_dump($return);`

Comment: Still getting errors, I've also messaged you in Facebook. (If you don't mind) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, although I technically have an FB account, I don't go there. Please continue to update your original post with more information. Let's focus solely on `sent.php`, too.

Comment: Post updated! 

Comment: A quick search for that error shows [this thread](https://github.com/berkayk/laravel-onesignal/issues/77) that includes many people's various solutions, none of which I can vouch for. Most require CLI access to the server to run. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this specific product so you might have to reach out to them directly to get more help. Good luck!